# Trouble connecting an action to a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, ibaction

I'm doing the iOS Apprentice Bundle and I'm not very good...

I was working through the tutorial when a "Done" button stopped working. It's attached to an IBAction that then calls self.delegate. I know this works as I added an NSLog but (after adding an NSLog at its destination) it's never reached. It's meant to add data the user inputted into a new table row.

Any help would be **really** appreciated! Thank you!

Here's the code:

ListDetailViewControllerTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ListDetailViewController;
@class Checklist;

@protocol ListDetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)listDetailViewControllerDidCancel:(ListDetailViewController *)controller;
- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist;
- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishEditingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist;
@end

@interface ListDetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ListDetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Checklist *checklistToEdit;

- (IBAction)cancel;
- (IBAction)done;

@end
```

ListDetailViewControllerTableViewController.m

```
    - (IBAction)done
    {

        if (self.checklistToEdit == nil) {
            Checklist *checklist = [[Checklist alloc] init];
            checklist.name = self.textField.text;
            [self.delegate listDetailViewController:self didFinishAddingChecklist:checklist];

        } else {
            self.checklistToEdit.name = self.textField.text;
            [self.delegate listDetailViewController:self didFinishEditingChecklist:self.checklistToEdit];
        }

        NSLog(@"Hello, I'm a 'Done' log");

    }
```

AllListsViewControllerTableViewController.m

```
- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist
{
    NSLog(@"Adding Checklist");

    controller.delegate = self;

    NSUInteger newRowIndex = [self.dataModel.lists count];
    [self.dataModel.lists addObject:checklist];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"finished adding checklist");
}
```

AllListsViewControllerTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ListDetailViewControllerTableViewController.h"
#import "DataModel.h"

@interface AllListsViewController : UITableViewController <ListDetailViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) DataModel *dataModel;

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you synthesizing the delegate? Also, it seems the delegate is being set in the `didFinishAddingChecklist` function, but it should be set when the ListDetailViewControllerTableViewController is created, or it will not know what object `self.delegate` is.

Comment: Do you only set the delegate in `listDetailViewController:didFinishedAddingChecklist:` ? or somewhere else too?

Comment: I create it here if that helps: 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ListDetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

in listDeatilViewControllerTableViewController.h

Comment: @Pfitz and here:


- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist;

in the same place

Comment: please check @rdelmar s answer. This will be most certainly your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you're setting the delegate -- you can't set it in the implementation of the delegate protocol method (listDetailViewController:didFinishAddingChecklist:), because that method is only called if the delegate is already set. You need to set the delegate when you  create an instance of the ListDetailViewControllerTableViewController class.